# Dbeaver doesn't delete columns in gui

Tags: dbeaver

[image]

I choose some rows, then tap to delete rows and then tap on Save.

But it's don't delete rows from table.

What am I doing wrong?

My table haven't primary key.
When I try to delete sime rows at the first time, dbeaver 
suggested that I use all the columns as a key:

[image]

Comment: Does your table have a primary key on it? I've run into issues modifying data in the GUI when there is no primary key on the table.

Comment: Yes, my table haven't primary key. I add the screenshot into question.

Comment: How did you solve this?